# rewrite on urls to add "/"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know how to rewrite urls to redirect to a page.

When the "/" is not at the end of www.DomainName.com/user/myUserName the redirect works:

```
RewriteRule /$ /user/index.php
```

When I write RewriteBase /  the above rule does not work, but a 404 error.

How to add a `"/"` at the end of `www.DomainName.com/user/myUserName/` and still redirect to `/user/index.php`.

This can be written into the .htaccess or httpd.conf

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the current contents of `.htaccess`?

Comment: : I want to know how to done???

Comment: @manish You want to know how to get done what?

Answer (score 0):

Hey, this is the default html access that I used.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# we skip all files with .something
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# we check if the .html version is here (caching)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# no, so we redirect to our front web controller
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I am a novice in the rewrite, so what part in your answer would the required answer to my question reflect

Comment: Well can you give me complete example of your code it will be easy to help you.